# How to use Google Analytics Android SDK Custom Metrics

Tags: android, sdk, google-analytics, metrics

I try to collect a custom metric from an Android application using Google Analytics SDK v3.

The doc says to do it like this :

```
// May return null if EasyTracker has not yet been initialized with a
// property ID.
EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance();


// Set the custom metric to be incremented by 5 using its index.
easyTracker.set(Fields.customMetric(1), 5);


// Custom metric value sent is with this screen view.
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
    .createAppView("Home screen")
    .build()
);
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/customdimsmets

However set(Fields.customMetric(1), 5); is undefined because only EasyTracker.set(String,String) exists. The documentation seems not up to date with the v3 SDK.

So here is what I tried instead :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();        
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();     
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  
    }   

    public void onDetected()
    {
        EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);
        easyTracker.set(Fields.customMetric(1), "1"); //not working
        easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
                .createEvent("cat", "detected", "beacon", (long) 1) // also tried with createAppView
                .set(Fields.customMetric(1), "1") // not working
                .set("&cm1", "1") // not working
                .build());  
    }
```

But none of this actually works. How can I collect custom metrics using Google Analytics Android SDK ?

Comment: I also opened an issue in GA tracking http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=410

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using the method:

```
Tracker.setCustomMetric(int, long)
```

I have done something similar with a custom dimension and it worked for me (tracker.setCustomDimension(String, string)).  Another gotcha that I ran into is that I had to make sure that the dimension was defined in the admin panel before GA would accept it.

Comment: Same problem here. I tried `setCustomMetric(int, float)` but it seems the custom metrics is not collected by analytics... (yes, the metric is defined in admin panel)